# PHP Method exist not working. How to resolve?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
if(function_exists($this->Common_model->disable_foreign_key_checks()) && function_exists($this->Common_model->increase_size_of_group_concat()) && function_exists($this->Common_model->increase_size_of_concat())){
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}
else{
    echo 'FAIL';
}
```

Anyone can please help me why function_exists not working? The project is based on CodeIgniter.

Comment: try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: Tried but nor worked that's why I asked a question.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you are right, too many unclosed questions.

Comment: Because you are not testing functions you are testing methods. It doesn't help that PHP uses the keyword  `function` when defining "methods" of a class. But there is a difference which is why there are two different "_exists" functions.

Answer (score 3):

use `method_exists` method here

```
 if (method_exists($this->Common_model, 'disable_foreign_key_checks')){
     echo 'SUCCESS';
 } else{
      echo 'FAIL';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems you completely misunderstand what `function_exists()` does and what it takes as an argument.

[`function_exists('function_name')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) returns `true` if a function named `'function_name'` has been defined or `false` if it has not.

Your code as written is using the return from a model to provide the `'function_name'` string. I seriously doubt any of those model methods return the name of a function.

I am going to make a wild guess at what you are really trying to do. I'm going to assume that each of the model functions will return true or false to indicate success or failure and you want to test for all three succeeding. If my guess is correct then this is the code you're looking for.

```
if($this->Common_model->disable_foreign_key_checks() && 
   $this->Common_model->increase_size_of_group_concat() && 
   $this->Common_model->increase_size_of_concat())
{
   echo 'SUCCESS';
}
else
{
   echo 'FAIL';
}
```